# Instant Search function is one keystroke behind

Tags: javascript, php

I have a type of "translate" program on my website that uses an instant search function. I have a textarea

```
<textarea name="text" onkeydown="searchq();"></textarea>
```

which runs the searchq() function

```
function searchq() {
    var searchTxt = $("textarea[name='text']").val();

    $.post("translate.php", {text: searchTxt}, function(output){
        $("#translated").html(output);
    });
}
```

which sends each word to the translate.php

```
if(isset($_POST["text"])){
    $words = explode(' ',$_POST['text']);

    $i = 0;
    foreach($words as $word){
        // performs transformations on the words
        $output = $word . " ";
        echo($output);
        $i++;
    }
}
```

However, if you try it out on my website http://saaa.me/MattSpeak.html, **you can clearly see that if you type in "y", nothing shows up, and only when you type in the next letter or space will the "y" show up. The instant translation process seems to be one character behind. What's causing this?** (the Trade Mark signs and "er" word endings are things that I added as part of the "translation")

I have a slight idea of why this isn't working properly but have no clue how to solve it. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `keydown` event *precedes* the character being added (even the `keypress` event precedes it). If you want to respond to a letter being typed, respond to `input` or, for older and/or buggy browsers (basically [IE9 and earlier](http://caniuse.com/#search=input)), respond to `keypress` with a brief `setTimeout`.

Using `input`:

```js
$("textarea").on("input", function() {
  $("<p>").text($(this).val()).appendTo(document.body);
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Using `keypress` with a `setTimeout` so the character gets added:

```js
$("textarea").on("keypress", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("<p>").text($this.val()).appendTo(document.body);
  }, 0);
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

I tend to respond to a range of events and use debouncing so I don't respond more than once:

```js
var lastSearch = null;
$("textarea").on("input keyup change", function() {
  var search = $(this).val();
  if (search !== lastSearch) {
    lastSearch = search;
    $("<p>").text(search).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @AndrewHu: *Probably*. Of course, you won't get a `keyup` event if the user right-clicked and pasted. You *will* get an `input` event in that situation (on browsers that support it).

Comment: Oh, that's true, especially since a lot of my friends said they wanted to paste selections of text into it. Looks like I'll be using your method then.

Comment: @AndrewHu: For things like this, I tend to respond to a bunch of events and use a brief delay (say, 20ms) before doing the actual work so I don't do the work repeatedly. I think my usual set is `input keyup change`.

Comment: I'll add something like that too. Thanks so much for the help, you're a good man.

Comment: @AndrewHu: I added an example of simple debouncing that's sufficient for this. I do recommend, btw, hooking up events as shown above rather than using old-fashioned `onxyz` attributes in the HTML. Regards,